# AWS EC2 NodeJS doesn't respond

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've got an AWS EC2 MEAN instance up and running (partially).  The app is a RESTful JSON service and as far as I can tell is up and running as expected:

```
var app = require('./app');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var server = app.listen(port, function() {
console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

console output:

node server.js

```
Express server listening on port 3000
Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be available in the 
next major release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow auth against 
users in the admin db and will no longer allow multiple credentials on 
a socket. Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth 
credentials.
```

I've also added the Inbound Security Group for port 3000 
[image: security group]

testing the API out in the browser is where I run into problems... If I attempt to GET a list of objects using http://ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.com:3000/belts the call eventually times out.  However when I try a GET for a single object using http://ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.com:3000/belts/some_id_here I get a valid 200 response with the expected object.

Of course everything works as expected locally.  What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

//edit with requested code formatted :)

//app.js

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express(); 
var BeltController = require('./controller/BeltController'); 
app.use('/belts', BeltController);
```

//Belt Controller

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) { 
    Belt.find({}, function (err, belts) { 
        if (err) { 
            return res.status(500).send("There was a problem finding the Belt. " + err); 
        } 
        res.status(200).send(belts); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: So propably the error is your route handler, post the code for the `belts list` route

Comment: sorry, I'm working to format the code so it displays neatly here

Comment: Edit your question with the code from the comment. WIll be a whole lot nicer to look at and debug.

Comment: It seems ok, try to put some console logs to see if the route's logic runs and if the query finishes with data or error.